# Asynchronous client ZeroMQ pattern

Tags: zeromq

I get the picture how to design a asynchronous server in ZeroMQ with several workers, but what is the correct way to create a asynchronous client with several workers? I've tried using a pattern similar to the server, using a proxy between a dealer frontend and a dealer backend. However, using this pattern I get bad performance and also seem to lose packets. That design then seems incorrect, so what is a suitable design pattern to use in the client?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed some code, or otherwise provide a more clear diagram of how you expect the communication flow to work.  In general ZMQ knows no real difference between "client" and "server", so any pattern that works for one will work for the other unless there are other details that aren't elucidated here.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Well, a router socket isn't useful in the client (and doesn't work to connect to other sockets, only to bind?) where you typically only have one connection. So the pattern isn't the same, right? Compare with figure 38 in ZeroMQ - The Guide.

Comment: A router socket could be used in the client, it can connect rather than bind, and it can connect to many peers.  But, if the socket type it's connecting to is also a router, it introduces potential issues. But, without you providing more details (such as code), making the client a dealer/dealer proxy doesn't really change the pattern as laid out in Fig. 38 in any appreciable way. Odds are you need to think out your communication protocol a little better.

Comment: As well the other things requested, it would be useful if you divulged the performance you are seeing vs. the performance you are expecting. You haven't said anything about the architechture of the client. Which platform? Is it single process, multi-thread; or multi-process? What transport are you using in the client? So much is left to guesswork that no-one can give a 'best' answer, or even a good answer.